# Convert from time character to time numerical variable in r

Tags: r, datetime, time, character, numeric

[Tibble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3x3u.png)

Hello! I am trying to change the Start.time variable from the character format of "4:00 PM" and take out the PM/AM and leave it as 4:00 as a numerical variable if possible. Thanks!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data (not a picture of it), all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `str_remove` to match zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by the letters 'A', 'P', 'M' at the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Start.time = str_remove(Start.time, "\\s*[APM]+$"))
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `sub`

```
df1$Start.time <- sub("\\s*[APM]+$", "", df1$Start.time)
```

Or with `substr`

```
trimws(substr(df1$Start.time, 1, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

`gsub("\\s*[APM]", "", start.time)` can be used to replace the string part after HH:MM with an empty string, leaving only the HH:MM bit.

`trimws(x)` replaces any leading whitespace in the string `x`.

```
> start.time
[1] "4:00 PM"  "12:00 AM" " 4:00 AM"

> trimws(gsub("\\s*[APM]", "", start.time))
[1] "4:00"  "12:00" "4:00"
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).